# Input any number and print all the odd number in descending order using while loop

Tags: java

How do i print all odd number in descending order?

```
int a = in.nextInt();
int counter = 0;

while(counter < a){
    if ((counter % 2) != 0){
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
    counter--;
}
```

*input: 10 Expected output: 9 7 5 3 1*

Comment: You are decreasing `counter`, which is initialized to `0` - this leads to `-1`, `-2` etc. And in your loop condition, the upper bound you check against is `a`, which is `10` in your example - this will always be true (until you hit overflow at the minimum integer).

Comment: you have to  set  the `count = a`  to work correctly

Comment: @MustafaPoya the condition is always false then... you neeed to change that as well

Comment: Sure the while condition also has problem: while (counter > 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```java
int a = in.nextInt();

while(a > 0){
    if ((a % 2) != 0){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    a--;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array of numbers, then sort it. add numbers to an array instead of printing numbers. Then sort the array. Then use a `foreach` to print all.

Answer (score 3):

use a for loop:

```
int a = in.nextInt();;
        
for(int i = a; i > 0; i--) {
    if(i % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need you use counter

```
int a = 10;

    while(a!=0){
        if ((a % 2) != 0){
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        a--;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```java
int a = in.nextInt();
if (a % 2 == 0) a--;

while (a > 0) {
    System.out.println(a);
    a -= 2;
}
```